# How to group similar names using PHP from mySQL results?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am running this query

```
SELECT distinct make, model FROM `used`order by make
```

in order to get all the available make / models in the database.

My end goal though is to edit the date using PHP and have this result:

```
 var alfa-romeo= '<select name="stage_type">
                    <option value="Mito">Mito</option>  
                </select>';
var audi= '<select name="stage_type">
                <option value="A4">A4</option>
                <option value="A5">A5</option>
                <option value="Allroad">Allroad</option>
          </select>';
```

for all the results.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: pleas append your php code and improve your question. Currently its unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cars;

CREATE TABLE cars
(car_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,make VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,model VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(make,model)
);

INSERT INTO cars (make,model) VALUES
('Alfa Romeo','Mito'),
('Audi','A4'),
('Audi','A5'),
('Audi','Allroad'),
('Audi','Q5'),
('Audi','S3'),
('Audi','SQ5'),
('Audi','TT'),
('BMW','1.14'),
('BMW','116'),
('BMW','320'),
('BMW','525'),
('BMW','X1'),
('BMW','X3'),
('BMW','X5'),
('Chevrolet','Aveo'),
('Chevrolet','Orlando'),
('Chevrolet','Spark'),
('Citroen','Berlingo'),
('Citroen','C-ELYSEE'),
('Citroen','C1'),
('Citroen','C3'),
('Citroen','C4'),
('Citroen','C4 Grand Picasso'),
('Citroen','C4 Picasso');

SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY make,model;
+--------+------------+------------------+
| car_id | make       | model            |
+--------+------------+------------------+
|      1 | Alfa Romeo | Mito             |
|      2 | Audi       | A4               |
|      3 | Audi       | A5               |
|      4 | Audi       | Allroad          |
|      5 | Audi       | Q5               |
|      6 | Audi       | S3               |
|      7 | Audi       | SQ5              |
|      8 | Audi       | TT               |
|      9 | BMW        | 1.14             |
|     10 | BMW        | 116              |
|     11 | BMW        | 320              |
|     12 | BMW        | 525              |
|     13 | BMW        | X1               |
|     14 | BMW        | X3               |
|     15 | BMW        | X5               |
|     16 | Chevrolet  | Aveo             |
|     17 | Chevrolet  | Orlando          |
|     18 | Chevrolet  | Spark            |
|     19 | Citroen    | Berlingo         |
|     20 | Citroen    | C-ELYSEE         |
|     21 | Citroen    | C1               |
|     22 | Citroen    | C3               |
|     23 | Citroen    | C4               |
|     24 | Citroen    | C4 Grand Picasso |
|     25 | Citroen    | C4 Picasso       |
+--------+------------+------------------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY make,model;
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $array[] = $row;
}

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $v){
   $new_array[$v['make']][] = $v['model'];
}


print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Alfa Romeo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mito
        )

    [Audi] => Array
        (
            [0] => A4
            [1] => A5
            [2] => Allroad
            [3] => Q5
            [4] => S3
            [5] => SQ5
            [6] => TT
        )

    [BMW] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.14
            [1] => 116
            [2] => 320
            [3] => 525
            [4] => X1
            [5] => X3
            [6] => X5
        )

    [Chevrolet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aveo
            [1] => Orlando
            [2] => Spark
        )

    [Citroen] => Array
        (
            [0] => Berlingo
            [1] => C-ELYSEE
            [2] => C1
            [3] => C3
            [4] => C4
            [5] => C4 Grand Picasso
            [6] => C4 Picasso
        )

)
```

Comment: What? You're not going to write the code to output the selects as well?! :-)

Comment: @Nick I assume that would be handled in the css - but feel free to edit

Comment: Yes this indeed is one off the most common way to do this.. But you made one error you didn't define the $new_array variable before using it in the foreach loop..